# Justify convergence of an integral

Tags: integration

How would I justify the convergence of the following integral?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{\log(x)} dx$$

---

So far I looked at the laurent series of $1/\log(x)$ and I tried graphing the functions involved https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jmputv2vmm to get some ideas but I don't know how to prove that two divergent terms together "cancel" to produce a convergent integral.

Comment: In Desmos use $\ln(x)$ for natural logarithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Apply L'Hopital's Rule twice to show that the integrand has limits $\frac 1 2$ at $1$. Apply L'Hopital's Rule once to show that the integrand has limits $1$  at $0$.  Since it is continuous on $(0,1)$ it the integral is convergent.